# How to display category image after resize in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am displaying any size image to fit in a 175x175 frame so it loses its original shape on the category page.

I want to display category image after resize that like product image is resized and displayed.

How can I do this in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Comment: try this - https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-resize-category-images (self)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to maually resize using Magento's image libs, herwes an example (http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-resize-image/):

```
// actual path of image
$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."myimage".DS.$post->getThumbnail();

// path of the resized image to be saved
// here, the resized image is saved in media/resized folder
$imageResized =     Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."myimage".DS."resized".DS.$post->getThumbnail();

// resize image only if the image file exists and the resized image file doesn't exist
// the image is resized proportionally with the width/height 135px
if (!file_exists($imageResized)&&file_exists($_imageUrl)) :
    $imageObj = new Varien_Image($_imageUrl);
    $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
    $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
    $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
    $imageObj->resize(135, 135);
    $imageObj->save($imageResized);
endif;

$newImageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."catalog/category/resized/".$imageName;
```

If you take a look at Varien_Image you will see there's a few different methods to help resize images. Unfortunately there's no helper to use as there is for product images, although it wouldn't be difficult to make a helper to do this.